# INSERT '100' into table IF '100' is the highest value gives error

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

According to [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html) this would run on mysql.version > 5. But I get:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'IF

Code:

```
IF SELECT MAX(`amount`) FROM transactions < 500 
THEN 
   INSERT INTO transactions (amount) VALUES (500)
END IF
```

or

```
IF( (SELECT MAX(`amount`) FROM transactions < 500)
     ,INSERT INTO transactions (amount) VALUES (500)
     , null
  );
```

Transactions table:

```
id amount
1  100
2  150
3  400
```

Neither work.

Comment: you need a where statement

Comment: Ok. 2 negative votes. What am I missing?

Comment: SELECT MAX(`amount`) FROM transactions WHERE amount < 500  Also, check your data types. in one line, you're using 500, on another, '500'

Comment: Posting sql code with a table schema would be helpful.

Comment: I guess Im too tired. Time to sleep. 04:10 AM here. Thanks for the help though! :)

Comment: I guess you definitely need that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the error is the fact that you can't use `IF` statement in plain query it can be used **only** in a context of a stored routine (procedure, function, trigger, event).

Your first piece of code will work successfully in a stored procedure *with shlight changes*

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE insert500()
BEGIN
  IF (SELECT MAX(`amount`) FROM transactions) < 500 -- see parenthesis around select
  THEN 
     INSERT INTO transactions (amount) VALUES (500); -- semicolon an the end
  END IF; -- semicolon an the end
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL insert500();
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/505c0/1)** demo

---

Now here is one way to do what you want in one statement

```
INSERT INTO transactions (amount)
SELECT 500
  FROM transactions
HAVING MAX(amount) < 500;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d30fb/1)** demo

Comment: The last one alone is enough to earn a +1.

Answer (score 0):

That should be:

```
IF SELECT MAX(`amount`) FROM transactions WHERE amount < 500 
THEN 
   INSERT INTO transactions (amount) VALUES (500)
END IF
```

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
SELECT MAX(`amount`) INTO m FROM transactions
IF m < 500
THEN 
   INSERT INTO transactions (amount) VALUES (500)
END IF
```

Check it and tell me please.

Comment: To those who down-rated my answer, please explain yourselves. It's counter-productive to just click a button to disprove something without stating the reason.